# Twilight theme for Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, themes

Is there a working Twilight theme for Netbeans 7? The one from nettutst doesn't work in Netbeans 7, just Netbeans 6.

Comment: I'm looking for this too, very frustrating to see google point me to a closed question that imho should not have been closed. I believe this to be a very relevant question!

Comment: There are other similar questions on SO about people asking for themes for NetBeans and they are still open. I get so annoyed with admins closing questions.